# Regex function to match a specific sequence of characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that would be True only in case that:

- it starts with `${` (1 time, `$` can only be there one time)
- after that any characters or nothing until `}` is found

This would match:

```
${
${test
test${test
${$fdsf$
${test}
```

This would not match:

```
$${
$${test
${test}test
```

Hopefully it's clear :)

Is that possible ?

Comment: `"test${test"` doesn't *start with `"${"`*. What does "1 time" mean the string `"${"` can only appear once in the string? If `"$"` must appear once obviously `"${"` can appear at most once. Can anything follow `"}"` if that character is present?

Comment: If my understand of the question is correct you can match the regular expression `^[^$}]*\$\{[^}]*\}?$`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j8fIz4/1). Hover the cursor over each part of this regex at the link to obtain an explanation of its function.

Answer (score 0):

Does that work for you?

`(?<!\$)\$\{[^}]*}?$`

https://regex101.com/r/g0vhJo/2

Comment: I am sorry I responded too quick, I just edited my answer!

Comment: This matches `'${${'`. Perhaps it should, but I can't tell from the wording of the question.

Comment: Do you have an alternative for this that would work as well on Safari ? Safari doesn't support look behind. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also use

```js
([^$\n]|^)\$\{[^}\n]*}?$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/O5O3QG/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^$\n]                   any character except: '$', '\n'
                             (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \$                       '$'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \{                       '{'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^}\n]*                  any character except: '}', '\n' (newline)
                           (0 or more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  }?                       '}' (optional (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```